# Video has become blurred and smoothed out?

Tags: graphics-card

Since yesterday, video and graphics on my Windows 7 desktop seem to have become smoothed out and blurred slightly. The last thing I did on the machine was play Fallout New Vegas for the first time.

[image: example]

Note how smoothed out the character on the right is - a lot of definition seems to have been lost. It's really annoying and happens regardless of what I watch.

My system specs are:

- Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit
- 6GB RAM
- Sapphire HD 5770 Vapor-X 1GB
- Gigabyte X58A-UD3R Motherboard
- Coolermaster Silent Pro M series 700W power supply

Any ideas what might be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed any new codecs lately? The fact that the screenshot shows the issue means it is definitely not a video card problem. You wouldn't be able to screenshot it if it was. I suggest trying to remove any new codecs, or, reverting to a system restore point to see if it makes any difference.

Edit: Upon second thought, it **could** be a video card issue if you've updated drivers lately. Try reverting to the previous drivers, or reinstalling the drivers and see what happens.

Comment: Hi,I've just updated the video card drivers and found no improvement.

Comment: I've also just noticed that the problem seems to be mainly in Windows Media Player. Its annoying as I prefer to use that for quickly opening videos. In DivX player and VLC things look fine - I dont want to have to use these though all the time and the change seems to have happened just recently. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't install any new codecs recently? Such as DivX? They override Windows' ones.

Comment: i think ive reinstalled DivX as part of the process of trying to fix this. The only notable thing that I'd done just before this problem occured was install Fallout New Vegas on the machine :-(